# Angular mat-tooltip calling a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to call a method selections() from button tooltip which does something and returns a string that needs to be displayed on hovering the tooltip. I tried interpolating the returned value on html, but it didn't work

**app.component.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button
      matTooltip={{selections()}}
      matTooltipClass = "test"
      aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered 
      over">
Action
</button>
```

The string "selected" needs to be returned from the function and to be displayed on hovering the tooltip

**app.component.ts**

```
selections() {
this.selectedelems = [];
this.selection.selected.map(id => this.tableData.data.filter((row: any) => 
{
  if (row._id === id) {
    this.selectedelems.push(row.name);
    this.selected = this.selectedelems.join('\r\n');
    }
}));
return this.selected;
}
```

Comment: Your `selections` function doesn't actually return a value-- you're only returning from the `filter` function

Comment: instead of {{ }} does it work any better if you do [matTooltip]="selections()"

Comment: @JBoothUA I tried that too.. still no help

Comment: @user184994 Awesome! It worked

Comment: @use184994 If you would like to convert your comment to answer, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a template expression via property binding.. the following should call your method and receive the returned string.

```
<button mat-raised-button
      [matTooltip]="selections()"
      matTooltipClass = "test"
      aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered 
      over">
Action
</button>
```

---

The following link is information on template expressions

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions

The following link is information on property binding

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding

---

**Please Note:**

> Although this is also a viable solution to populating the tooltip via
>   component method, per the comments below this was not the root issue
>   to this question and interpolation would have worked in this scenario
>   as well. `matTooltip="{{selections()}}"`

Comment: It also worked for string interpolation.. where I missed was I am not returning from the selections() instead I am returning from the filter()

Comment: You are correct, interpolation works and this answer is not the root issue, would you like me to delete this answer?

Comment: I placed the note on this answer for clarification of future readers as I had 2 up votes received; did not expect you to accept it as the answer. If @user184994 would like to covert comment to answer please accept that answer as it should truly be marked as the correct answer in this case.